# R maximize a list of matrices

Tags: r, matrix

I have a `d`-length list of matrices of the same `m*n` dimension (actually it is a tensor of `m*n*d` but I don't know how to store it in that way). I would like to compare all matrices on the same element position and output a matrix with the largest element in each position. Specifically, the list of matrices are `l = {l[[1], ..., l[[dd]],..., l[[d]]}`. The output should be a matrix `mat` where `mat[i,j] = max(l[[dd]][i,j])` `for all dd`.

I know one of the feasible solution is to vectorize all matrices and then use pmax() but it is very slow. Can anyone suggest a quicker way to do it please? Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

You could simplify to an array and then use `apply`. If `matrices` is your list of matrices, then the following computes what you want:

```
apply(simplify2array(matrices),c(1,2),max)
```

Comment: Thanks! May I know what 'c(1,2)' here is working for?

Comment: `c(1,2)` are the dimensions that you fix. The third dimension is the dimension that the function is applied over. Honestly, I had to look at the documentation (via `?apply`) to remember how it worked for arrays. I have used `apply` numerous times over matrices but relatively few times over arrays.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `Reduce` with `pmax`...

```
#some dummy data...
l <- list(matrix(1:4,nrow=2),matrix(5:2,nrow=2),matrix((0:3)*2,nrow=2))

l
[[1]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    1    3
[2,]    2    4

[[2]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    3
[2,]    4    2

[[3]]
     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    0    4
[2,]    2    6

Reduce(pmax,l)

     [,1] [,2]
[1,]    5    4
[2,]    4    6
```

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion! However, the function pmax is too slow and the R studio died...